# Address entry on the new PayPal mobile SDK and 3D secure

Tags: paypal

Does the new PayPal mobile SDK require the user to enter their address information when they pay with credit card?

We have tried the SDK and we can see that PayPal does not ask the user for their address information. However, we are not sure if this works conditionally.

Further, what if the user's card is protected with 3D secure. Does PayPal show the 3D secure page to the user? If not, will the transaction fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mido, Dave from PayPal here.

No, the mobile SDK never asks a user for address information.

3D Secure is not an issue for the mobile SDK. mSDK will never present a 3D Secure page to the user, and 3D Secure authentication is not required for the transaction to be processed successfully by PayPal.